# matching Charaters in soql query

Tags: apex, soql

I have written the below to match postcodes with a custom obect for account allocation as is suggested best practice

```
    trigger PostcodeBulk on Account (before insert) {

    Set<String>Postcode = new set<String>();

    For(Account acc : trigger.new) {
        if (acc.billingpostalcode != null){
            postcode.add(acc.BillingPostalCode);
        }
    }
Map<String,String> postcodeowner = new map<string,string>();
    For (postcodes__c P : [select postcode__c, user__c from postcodes__c where postcode__C in :postcode]);
        postcodeowner.put(p.postcode__c,p.user__c);

    For(account acc : trigger.new){
        if(postcodeowner.containsKey(acc.BillingPostalCode)){
            acc.OwnerId = postcodeowner.get(acc.BillingPostalCode);
        }
    }
           }
```

my problem is that I only need to make the match on upto the first 4 characters, but sometimes less..

I thought of

```
if (acc.billingpostalcode != null){
            postcode.add(acc.BillingPostalCode.substring(0,4));
```

But this only matches exact I need to add a wildcard somewhere for example

```
[select postcode__c, user__c from postcodes__c where postcode__C in ::postcode.substring(0,2) + '%']
```

But I cannot make this work

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wildcard expressions with a SOQL IN operator.  You should use the LIKE operator

```
  string postCodeSearch = postCode.substring(0,2) + '%';

  list<postcodes__c> codes = [select postcode__c, user__c from postcodes__c where postcode__C LIKE :postCodeSearch];
```

Comment: its returns and error

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [set<String>].substring(Integer, Integer)

I can solve this by adding [0] to postcode[0].substring

surely this will only check the first record in the list?

Comment: Yes, postcode[0].substring() will only return the substring of first element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the :: variable in the SOQL statement, set a string variable above it that takes the postcode substring, and add the `'%'` to it, then use that variable in the SOQL statement